# How much time is involved in migrating Magento to a new server?

Tags: magento, migration, web-hosting, dedicated-server

I have Magento 1.6 site currently operational and am having a 3rd party migrate the site to a new server and having it upgraded to latest version (1.8). I also have 5 exentions that will be updated as well. I will also require all product and customer data be transfered.

Assuming all of the extensions are compatible with 1.8 what sort of labor time would be invovled in moving eveything over to the new server and getting it operational? Just looking for a rough estimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Four days ± two days. It might be plain sailing => two days. But there can be complications and it will need thoroughly tested. 'Updating 5 plugins' could be time consuming and don't forget the SSL certificate and setting and testing the payment system to respond to the new IP address.